# Stopping a program from within a class in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class:

```
class A:
   def command(self, input):
       if command == 'test1':
            do something...
       if command == 'quit':
            #stop the program
```

and outside the class I initiate a while loop:

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
    lst = A()
    while True:
        command = input("Enter an option:")
        lst.command(command)
```

I'm stuck at the point where if the command is 'quit', I need to stop the whole program from running. The problem I'm facing now is that since I initiated a while loop outside the class, how do I 'False' the loop in order to stop the whole program?

I'm looking for either a break method or perhaps creating another function to quit the program entirely but not the `sys()` or `quit()` method which I'm guessing I'm not allowed to do so.

Comment: [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sys.exit()` or a similar "nuclear" function anywhere in a class is usually a bad idea. (And so is having a `while True` loop.) Instead, let the loop break naturally and gracefully.

First, your `command` must return a sentinel when it receives a `"quit"`. The value of the sentinel is application-dependent; let's say it is `None`:

```
if command == 'quit': 
    return None
```

The loop should watch the returned value and break when the sentinel is returned:

```
lst = A()
command = input("Enter an option:")
while command is not None:        
    lst.command(command)
    command = input("Enter an option:")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just move the quit command outside the `command` function.

```
class A:
    def command(self, inp):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    lst = A()
    while True:
        cmd = input("Enter an option: ")
        if cmd.lower() == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            lst.command(cmd)

print('thanks bye!!')
```

It's often good to decouple the quit action from other application commands. Your `A` class need not know about the application quit mechanism (and could therefore be reused in other apps with a different quit mechanism).

I also made it so that it will not be case sensitive. So `quit`, `Quit` or `QUIT` will all trigger the action.